# Ubuntu 22.04 ethernet issue

Tags: internet, ethernet

I've connected my laptop with Ethernet but I cannot access to the web though my connection is reconised by Ubuntu with a comnected status.
So Firefox does not work and I cannot update packages as no access to internet.
Many thanks for your help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.